# Moment of Inertia of Rolling Concentric Disks

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, moment-of-inertia

Imagine I have 2 concentric disks, one with radius R1 and the other with radius R2, each one with homogeneously distributed masses M1 and M2 respectively. If I apply a moment on the disk by pulling on the smaller disk with an ideal rope, and the system rolls without slipping, what would be the moment of inertia of the system and the linear acceleration of the center of mass?

Image of system:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the total moment of inertia about the center of mass add the contributions from each of the disks. You have clockwise torques about the CM: F$R_1$ + f$R_2$, where F is your pull on the rope and f is friction from the surface.  Also F – f = ($M_1 + M_2$)a, and a = $R_2$α.